# How to write from one text file to another file on separate lines

Tags: php

The source file has the phone numbers like this:

```
8076130581  8070200776  8071768383  8075591843
```

I want the target file to have the numbers ilke this:

```
08076130581
08070200776
08071768383
08075591843
```

My problem is the output to the target file's. Thus:
  08076130581   8070200776  8071768383  8075591843
  08070200776    8071768383 8075591843

My code:

```
$source = 'Path/To/Source.txt';
$target = 'Path/To/Target.txt';

$lines = file($source);

foreach($lines as $line)
{
  /* Split each line into an array */
  $splitting = explode(' ', $line);
  foreach($splitting as $phone_number)
  {
    /* Store each array value with a leading zero into a temporary $variable */
    $each_phone_number[] = '0' . trim($phone_number) . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

/*Write the content back to another file*/
file_put_contents($target, $each_phone_number);
```

Comment: soo what exactly is your problem?

Comment: the number of phone numbers on each line in the source file varies.
I want to output each phone number to the target file. Each phone number on a separate line with a zero in front of each.

Comment: yeah, you explained what you want to achieve. but not what your actual problem on the way of achieving it is.

Comment: The problem:
The target file gets the output but with a zero before the first phone number on each line. Each line is still an array. rather than a phone number string.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your script against your source example.

It appears that there is one blank espace missing in the line

`$splitting = explode(' ', $line);`

You should write instead :

`$splitting = explode('  ', $line);`

If the space is consistent between the phones in your `source.txt` it should solve the problem and create the expected target file

Comment: .: there's a space there

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I have rewritten it and tested it again. same problem:
The output is still in 5 columns rather than 1 phone number on each line